# Best alternative to Scientific Workplace 5.5

Tags: scientific-workplace

The company has gone out of business-sadly for me! I am now very used to typesetting documents on Scientific Workplace 5.5. I am looking for a software package that combines the ability to edit documents in LaTeX and do mathematics-plot graphs, solve algebraic equations, do calculus, simplify algebraic expressions. All of this is possible on Scientific Workplace 5.5 as of now. Any suggestions? I am not very computer savvy-so an option "for dummies" would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The proprietary's website (www.mackichan.com) says that you will still be able to use their software if you bought a license, so that shouldn't be an issue...

Comment: Maybe [LyX](https://www.lyx.org)? But it might not capable of everything you listed and is primarily for typesetting. Like WYSIWYG for LaTeX.

Comment: "do mathematics-plot graphs, solve algebraic equations, do calculus, simplify algebraic expressions"... it is different tasks and for different tasks You will need different packages, just start with some idea, for example "I wanna plot something" and You will find answer in the internet 100%

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik isn't it only for two years? Or is that activation of reinstall of an existing license?

Comment: You can still use 5.5 for the rest of your life. Company went out of business, but the you still have the software. So keep using it. There will not be an update. But that is OK. I use SW 5.5. everyday. I agree, it is the best, but company went horrible with wasting time on version 6.0 and it costs them the whole company.

Comment: Thanks Nasser! I agree completely. I bought version 6 and returned it because it was really bad.